# Add a class to react-day-picker?

Tags: react-day-picker

How can I add a class to react-day-picker's today button?

It seems to be possible from the documentation:
http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPicker#classNames

```
const dayPickerClassNames = { todayButton: 'newClass' };

<DayPicker
  classNames={dayPickerClassNames}
/>
```

However Im getting an error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `classNames.day` is marked as required in `DayPicker`, but its value is `undefined`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API, it expects the following keys (ie, it needs the container, wrapper, .. months.. month.. day.. etc. keys), but you are only providing the todayButton key/value, apparently you need to provide each key/value pair.

You should be able to import the default `classNames` object, and then just update the `todayButton` value like so:

```
import classNames from '../classNames' // this path is probably not correct

const dayPickerClassNames = { ...classNames, todayButton: 'newClass' };

<DayPicker
  classNames={dayPickerClassNames}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const defaultClassNames = DayPicker.defaultProps.classNames,
      newClassNames = { ...datePickerClassNames,
                        container: `${defaultClassNames.container} MY_CONTAINER`
                      };

...

<DayPicker classNames={dayPickerClassNames}/>
```

I'd recommend appending the default class with your own as in the example above the default `container` class appended with `MY_CONTAINER` class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may just be parsing the word `day` and looking for a className for that parsed `day*******` I think I would just try defining the `key:value` relationship as they have in their documentation.

```
// const dayPickerClassNames = { todayButton: 'newClass' };

<DayPicker
  classNames={ todayButton: 'newClass' }
/>
```

Comment: Nope, this crashes my app: imports/client/Pages/Events/EventsPage.js:258:42: Unexpected token, expected } (258:42)

Comment: It needs to be `classNames={ { todayButton: 'newClass'  } }` for it not to crash